# Renaming all files in folder in Bash

Tags: bash

How to rename all the files in the directory in such a way the files get added "_1" before ".txt"

```
apac_02_aug_2017_file.txt
emea_02_May_2017_file.txt
ger__02_Jun_2017_file.txt
```

To

```
apac_02_aug_2017_file_1.txt
emea_02_May_2017_file_1.txt
ger__02_Jun_2017_file_1.txt
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## With rename

`rename .txt _1.txt *` should do what you are looking for.

To quote `man rename`:

> rename [options] expression replacement file...
>
> rename will rename the specified files by replacing the first occurrence of expression in their name by replacement.

---

## With common bash commands

Since you said that `rename` is not installed on your system, here's a solution that uses more standard Bash:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    mv "$file" "${file%.txt}_1.txt"
done
```

Explanation: We loop over all files. For each file, we move it to the correct location by making use of something called "parameter expansion" (this is the `${}` part). The special character `%` can be used within parameter expansion to match a pattern at the end of the string and delete it.

For further information, see: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#from_the_end

Answer (score 0):

Through `mmv` it's mush easy:

```
mmv '*.*' '#1_1.#2' *.txt
```